# Get meta after running mutation

Tags: rtk-query

After running the mutation, I want to get the `meta` returned by `baseQuery`. I printed the result, but there is no `meta` in it. Is there any way to get the meta here?

```js
const [addPost, { isLoading }] = useAddPostMutation();
// ...
const handleAddPost = async () => {
  const result = await addPost(post);
  console.log(result);
  // => { data: {...} }
  // but required this: { data: {...}, meta: { ... } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access `meta` in `transformResponse` and make it part of `data` - after that it is thrown away.

Comment: I have some *non-serializable* values in `meta`, they are not data, and I don't want to put them in store, these values are *only* used in the `handleAddPost` callback for reporting data (our base library needs to use it, yes, a non-serialized value, I can't change the implementation of the base library). Thanks a lot for your answer, is there any solution for my scenario?

Comment: You could move that code into the `onQueryStarted` lifecycle, that also has access to `meta`. But `meta` will never be available in your component, since that would mean it would need to go to store - and you noticed correctly: we don't want non-serializable values in there.